# Can a place be "drop dead gorgeous"?

Tags: idioms, idioms-in-context

I have heard people use "drop dead gorgeous" for handsome or beautiful people. But can this idiom be used for beautiful places?

Comment: [This definition](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/drop-dead-gorgeous) gives one example relating to scenery and one to food, among many relating to people.

Comment: Sarah, yes you can.

Comment: @KateBunting - A quick Google shows 'drop-dead gorgeous' cats, cakes, dogs, dog's tooth violets, a chicken (a hen, a Silver-Laced Wyandotte), gardens, plenty of cars, houses, and then I got bored. I think that it has escaped its informal origin (and therefore loose confines), out into the wild. Outside into the sweet night air, as Tom Stoppard might have said.

Answer (score 3):

My first inclination was to agree with other answers here that "drop dead gorgeous" was only (or mostly, or typically) used in reference to human people. But my interest was piqued by one of the comments referencing the phrase's occurrence in the [iWeb Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/iweb/).* A search there reveals that "drop dead gorgeous" is not only used to refer to things other than people, but that those types of references are, in fact, fairly common.

This is a very unscientific sample, but below are the first ten results for "drop dead gorgeous" in the iWeb Corpus:

> 1. I think we can all agree that she is drop dead gorgeous. Her husband, however...
> 2. ...Venturi [a car] because its engineering was superb.. it still to this day is drop dead gorgeous...
> 3. ...why not take up X Theme on the invitation to customize some drop dead gorgeous registration forms for your site?...
> 4. Drop dead gorgeous, sassy and smart, Ruby Wax brings her new one-woman show to the stage...
> 5. ...quickly earned herself the label of drop dead gorgeous online...
> 6. She is drop dead gorgeous and somewhat of a flirt...
> 7. While the Corvette looks great, its not drop dead gorgeous like the Jaguar....
> 8. It conjures up an image of a drop dead gorgeous young man with dark hair...
> 9. A drop dead gorgeous real wedding with a serene ceremony in Killruddery's glass orangery...
> 10. There it was buried in a HomeGoods aisle... a drop dead gorgeous acacia wood tray....

As we can see, **five of the first ten** results use "drop dead gorgeous" to refer to something that's not a person (i.e. cars, a wedding, registration forms, a wooden tray). I didn't do an exhaustive review, but found one (likely among many) explicitly referring to a place:

> 68. ...Accommodations on a magnificent white sandy beach facing a drop dead gorgeous south pacific lagoon of crystal clear water...

A cursory glance through the more than 1,200 results suggests the above are not anomalies. Thus, it appears that "drop dead gorgeous" *is* used fairly commonly to refer to inanimate objects, including places.

---

*Searching in this corpus requires registration, which, unfortunately, may also require attesting to affiliation with a university (although that affiliation doesn't appear to be verified during registration).

Comment: +1 I don't think you have to have any university affiliation to register, btw. This seems to be back up by the "other" field on the registration page.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I think you're right, although when I chose "other" as a test I think it still wanted me to specify an affiliation on a subsequent screen. But if so, it seems you can choose any institution and that's that, they don't require an institutional email address or any other sort of verification. So in any case, effectively you don't need affiliation.

Answer (score 1):

I've only ever heard it said about people. It seems a variation of the idiom *to knock (one) dead*, meaning to *strongly impress*. While a place or a thing can be described as impressive, 'knocking someone dead' in this metaphorical way can also be a deliberate act - "knock them dead!" is often said as words of encouragement to someone wanting to make an impression. So you can see why this idiom on which it is likely based is specific to people.

The word 'gorgeous' alone does have a wider use with places and things, but I've never heard anyone describe anything like that as 'drop dead' gorgeous and, speaking as a native British English speaker, it sounds odd to me.

The fact that written examples seemingly to the contrary have been cited in other answers does not change my stance on this. It isn't uncommon for writers to use out-of-context idioms in order to make a point stand out. When you read something that wouldn't sound right spoken there is a good chance you'll read it twice to make sure, which is exactly what the writers of advertising material want. Some of these examples sound like promotional or advertising material for cars and the like. It is also not uncommon for vehicles to be personified.